# Prompting user input in Visual Basic 2010 two dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I prompt the user to input elements in a two dimensional array? And how do I then save the output?

I've figured out how write and print a program where the program provides the elements (see short version below), but I can't work out how to get the user to input the elements instead.
Many thanks.

```
Solfa(0, 0) = 11
Solfa(0, 1) = 12
Solfa(1, 0) = 21
Solfa(1, 1) = 22
TextBox1.Text = Solfa(0, 0) & " " & Solfa(0, 1) & vbCrLf & Solfa(1, 0) & " " & Solfa(1, 1)
```

Comment: What presentation library are you using? WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET?
What about a databound grid?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a grid (if your presentation framework has one).
Otherwise, you can use an multi-line textbox that is pre-populated with a comma-separated list of values, like this:

```
11, 12
21, 22
```

Then, you can parse the user-edited values again (the easiest way being)

```
For Each line in input.Split (vbCrLf)
   For Each field in line.Split (", ".ToCharArray())
      // Plug back into array.
      // Don't forget bounds-checking.
   Next
   // Don't forget bounds-checking.
Next
```